# Yii2 Google 0auth2 URI redirect issue

Tags: php, yii2, google-signin

I created a G+ login credential to my application through 0auth2.

```
 'google' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOAuth',
            'clientId' => '*****************',
            'clientSecret' => 'j*************',
        ],
```

The above code is from my config/web.php. and this is my action in controller

```
'auth' => [
            'class' =>'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
            'successCallback' => [
            $this, 'successCallback'
            ],
```

every thing is fine..but got some error while returning back.
The error is
 **Error: redirect_uri_mismatchThe redirect URI in the request: http://localhost/mysite/site/auth?authclient=google did not match a registered redirect URI.**
Can any one tell me why this happening and what I am missing...
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add `returnUrl` explicitly in your auth client configuration. Look at [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-authclient-baseoauth.html#%24returnUrl-detail) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,But I already tried this one.I was unable to take the attributes by this method